# asp net mvc core2 при передачи datetime в метод контроллера меняются местами дата и месяц

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

asp net mvc core2 при передачи datetime в метод контроллера меняются местами дата и месяц.

```
  public async Task Index(DateTime? dateStart,DateTime? dateEnd)
        {         
                ViewBag.dateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-47).Date.ToString();
                ViewBag.dateEnd = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();                 
        }
```

Представление:

```
 <input type="text" id="dateTimeStart" class="form-control text-center datetimepicker" name="dateStart" value=@ViewBag.dateStart>
```

JavaScript где происходит форматирование даты

```
 $('#dateTimeEnd').datetimepicker({
    lang: 'ru',
    i18n: {
        ru: {
            months: [
                'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель',
                'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август',
                'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь',
            ],
            dayOfWeek: [
                "По", "Вт", "Ср",
                "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вc",
            ]
        }
    },
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'd.m.Y'
});
```

Отправляю 07.10.2017, а в представление уже приходит 10.07.2017, а вот кто меняет 
не понятно 
    Cтрока GET запроса `http://localhost:52764/CallLaters?dateStart=08.03.2017&dateEnd=14.10.2017`

Comment: Ну так проверяйте запросы, смотрите где какие языковые настройки

Comment: Что то не нашел где они есть эти языковые настроки?

Comment: windows -> панель управления -> региональные стандарты -> Форматы дат и времени. Я подозреваю, что либо на сервере, либо на клиенте вы сохраняете/парсите дату учитывая региональные настройки, хотя надо это делать культуронезависимым способом.

Comment: Сервер и место отладки одно и тоже, в системных настройках указано dd.MM.YYYY т.е указано правильно, а приходит меняет местами

Comment: Так оно меняет местами когда приходит в контроллер или когда уходит из браузера?

Comment: Когда при ходит в контроллер

Comment: Значит, копайте настройки парсинга даты для вашего десериализатора.